# Paste text from text file into worksheet line by line

Tags: vba, excel, text

I have the following code for pasting text from a text file into my worksheet. Problem is it dumps it all on one line!

For example if the text file reads:

```
Opened by Joe Bloggs 24 Feb 2017 11:08:12
Closed by Joe Bloggs 24 Feb 2017 11:23:12
```

This will all be pasted into Range("A1") as:

```
Opened by Joe Bloggs 24 Feb 2017 11:08:12 Closed by Joe Bloggs 24 Feb 2017 11:23:12.
```

I would rather it was pasted line by line down column A, such that:

```
Range("A1").Value = Opened by Joe Bloggs 24 Feb 2017 11:08:12
Range("A2").Value = Closed by Joe Bloggs 24 Feb 2017 11:23:12
```

**My Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, Delimiter As String

myFile = "J:\...\Group Jobslist V1.2. Log.Log"

Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1
Range("A1").Value = text

End Sub
```

Comment: The `Documentation` facility has some excellent examples to help you with this. Check out the `Do While` loop which contains an incrementing variable - that's what you're after as a first step (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures#t=201702261159580372731).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply print each line in the loop.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myFile As String, textline As String
    myFile = "J:\...\Group Jobslist V1.2. Log.Log"

    Dim i As Long
    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        i = i + 1
        Line Input #1, textline
        Range("A" & i).Value = textline
    Loop
    Close #1

End Sub
```

You could also use the FileSystemObject instead of older code style.

Comment: Glad to help out. Can you accept my answer by checking the box?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, you can save each row (from Text file) to an array element, and afterwards just loop through all array elements and print them in Column A (row by row).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline() As Variant, Delimiter As String
Dim i As Long

myFile = "J:\...\Group Jobslist V1.2. Log.Log"
ReDim textline(1 To 1000) '<-- Init array to large size

i = 1
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline(i)
    text = text & textline(i)
    i = i + 1
Loop
Close #1

ReDim Preserve textline(1 To i - 1) '<-- resize array to number of lines

' loop through all array elements and print each one in column A (new row)
For i = 1 To UBound(textline)
    Range("A" & i).Value = textline(i)
Next i

End Sub
```